# Update pom.xml if parent or certain dependencies have newer versions available, Jenkins pipeline with maven?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml, parent-pom

Trying to figure out the right approach for updating pom.xml if parent or (certain) dependencies have updates available in nexus repository, and only then build new artifact with Jenkins.

So basically, build new version of 'Testing-app-for-version-update' if there are new releases of parent or dependency apps.

App pom looks like:

```
<version>1.0.0</version>               // <-- Version to update
<name>Testing-app-for-version-update</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
 <groupId>com.test.testing</groupId>
 <artifactId>testing-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0</version>              // <---- Update pom version if never version
</parent>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.test.testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>app2</artifactId>   
  <version>1.0</version>                // <---- Update pom version if never version
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.test.testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>app3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>               // <---- Update pom version if never version
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <artifactId>dependency1</artifactId> // <--- No need to update pom version
  <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

I was wondering about using:`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`, but reading the output feels a bit "hackish" approach.
Is there way to use mvn for this?

Comparing the pom versions to released artifacts also feels glumsy? Any other solutions how to create Jenkins pipeline for building new app version, when pom.xml needs to be updated?

Also calling this after app2 or app3 build pipelines are finished, is problematic as the pipeline would be called twice, once the app2 has finished and again app3 has finished. So I would like launch this "update app version" pipeline manually. And I have other applications where version needs to updated as well.

Comment: Still wondering is this this good solution for the pipeline / continuous integration, but I have not found anything else. So trying to use the "versions:use-latest-versions" instead of "versions:display-dependency-updates" as it does have the -Dincludes parameter for the groupid.